# Physical meaning of electric dipole moment

Tags: electrostatics, dipole, dipole-moment

I am reading about the electric dipole moment. What I can't understand, and seems that no one cares to explain, is what is the physical meaning of it. To my understanding everytime that dipoles are "examined" the dipole moment is essential regarding to the understanding of their properties, but I don't understand what is its physical meaning and why it is so important to dipoles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient prior research effort.

Comment: Insufficient research effort? What I have to do to prove sufficient research effort in such a question? By the way believe me I have searched extensively as I say in my question (although quite vaguely).

Comment: You can read up on wikipedia/search on google on the topic, and then come back with specific questions, stating what you understand and what you don't.  Try to be **precise**, so people know **what** you want to know. (Assume that people will put a comparable amount of effort in their answer as you put into your question.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have obviously read wikipedia and Google up to its 3rd page. I can also cite to you 3 textbooks that I currently have opened in front of me tryhing to answer this question. My question is crystal clear: what is the physical meaning of the electric dipole moment.

Comment: The dipole moment tells you how much (i.e. with which torque) an object wants to align along an electric field. But I assume you read that on wikipedia?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch no Wikipedia was stating that dipole moment "is a measure of the separation of positive and negative electrical charges in a system of electric charges" but this doesn't explan anything as I don't really underastand its use. If you know the answer there is no point in discussing it in comments as you can post it. I think your contribution can be very helpful.

Comment: Just after that, wikipedia starts talking about torque etc.. What don't you like about that? -- Do you have a good understanding what mass is, to give us an analogy what you consider a "physical meaning"?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch in the section about torque it just mentions what happens in a dipole when subjected to a force, that is not the physical meaning. Physical meaning is quite abstrach it is how can someone understand what is the use of the dipole moment in nature and not theoretically (i.e ease of calculations). I for example know what a dipole is and know how to calculate the moment but I don't understand why it is so useful when we examine dipoles and what shows us about them.

Comment: Do you believe there should be some metaphysical importance to the term dipole moment, or would you be satisfied that the dipole moment simply represents a calculated quantity that routinely shows up and can be used in an analogous way when more complicated charge distributions are de-constructed into a sum of multipole moments?

Comment: @BillN I don't know why there is so dicussion regarding such a simple question. I don't ask anything peculiar or metaphysical, I am more than happy with the "answer" you just said if you post it well explained.

Comment: Why people have voted to close with the reason that "this question does not appear to be about physics within the scope defined in the help center" when there are at least 3 answers posted as comments and there are hundreds of question about the physical meaning of quantities in this site and most textbooks give the physical meaning of the quantities they explain everytime (although I couldn't find this one)? What is not physical about this question? How simpler can it be? I am genuinely perplexed regarding the discussing this question has triggered. I ask people that voted to reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

The dipole moment is defined as a system of two charges that are very close to each other. In doing so, we find that there the potential now experimentally measured is inversely proportional to the square root of the distance between the centre of dipole to the measuring point and is directly proportional to the cosine of angle as measured from the line joining the two charges. Now barring the constants we have an extra term which dictates the strength of the electric field which is given by $p = q.d$ where d is the distance between the two charges.

The physical importance of the dipole moment term in the electric potential can now be easily understood to be the second order term $(0(1/r^2))$ in the electric potential, where the first order term has been cancelled out due to equal charges placed closely and so giving a net charge 0$(O(1/r))$. So physically the dipole moment is a measure of the residual electric potential that remains even if the the net charge of the system is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a dielectric is placed in an electrid field. We want to study its effect on electric field. It can be proven its electric effect can be described only with its charge (which is assumed to be zero) and its dipole vector density. So for instance it is important to know what is the electric potential of a dipole; because once you know the effects of a small charge and a small dipole, then you know the effect of all dielectrics with precision.